# How to control the behavior of React Navigation's focusHandler

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

With Drawer Navigation of React Navigation, I created Navigation with the following structure.

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="First" component={First} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Second" component={Second} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Third" component={Third} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

And each Drawer Screen component has the structure of Stack Navigation and looks like the one below. I created Providers using `useContext` in each Drawer Component.(FirstProvider, SecondProvider, ThirdProvider)

```
<FirstProvider>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="FirstScreen" component={FirstScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FirstDetail" component={FirstDetail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</FirstProvider>
```

And I defined the **focusHandler** function in `FirstScreen` as below. In the case of **firstFunc**, it is a function obtained from `FirstProvider`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const focusHandler = navigation.addListener("focus", firstFunc);
    return focusHandler;
}, []);
```

What I'm curious about is: Is it possible to make **foucsHandler** only work when `Drawer Navigation` changes?

For example, after moving from `FirstScreen` to `FirstDetail`, I want the **focusHandler** not to work when I go back to `FirstScreen`.

As another example, if I move from `First` to `Second` through the Drawer and then return to First, I want the **focusHandler** of `FirstScreen` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the focus listener to be called only when the focus status of `First` screen changes and not for `FirstScreen` screen, then you have to move the logic to the `First` screen.

If you really need that logic in `FirstScreen`, then you can use `useIsFocused()` in `First` screen and pass it down to `FirstScreen` via context to do something when it changes.